# Ionic popup invisible on device but showing in chrome's inspector

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, ionic-popup

I use an Ionic popup in my app that works perfectly in the browser.

The problem happens when I run it on my `Android 6.0.1` device, the popup is invisible just in one view (if I randomly click on the screen I can press the close button).

What makes me mad is that if I open chrome's inspector to see what's going on the popup is visible in the preview!

**EDIT** The problem is caused by a conflict with IonicNativeTransition, disabling it solves the issue.

Why is the inspector not showing what I see on my device?

PS: This is what I mean for chrome's preview

[image]